# CUDA ECC performance cost

Tags: performance, cuda

What is the performance cost of running a CUDA device with ECC on? Peak performance of GPUs is usually quoted with ECC off, how can I find out what is the theoretical limit with ECC on?

@edit
For the sake of this question, assume I have a completely memory-bound kernel, which simply moves data around. Any arithmetic is irrelevant to the running time as it can be scheduled when the memory units are busy. With ECC off, theoretically, I could obtain a peak memory bandwidth as quoted in device specification. What is the peak I can obtain with ECC on?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by peak performance? ECC effects memory bandwidth, it has nothing to do with arithmetic performance

Comment: The impact of ECC on realizable memory bandwidth utilization varies based on a number of factors, including but not limited to, device type and memory access pattern specifics.  I don't know of published information that spells this out to a complete level of detail. Reasonable estimates can be made using the `bandwidthTest` [cuda sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#bandwidth-test).  As @talonmies has indicated, the only direct effect is on the memory subsystem(s), not on the actual compute resources of the GPU.  I suspect this question is unanswerable as written.

Comment: I've added more information to the question. Basically it comes down to 'If I can move X GB of data in a second with ECC off, how much can I move in a second with ECC on?'.

Comment: There is still no answer because it varies by device type and access pattern.  Again, if you just want a single estimate, use the cuda `bandwidthTest` sample code, on your particular device.

Comment: I am getting only 75% of the peak memory bandwidth with ECC off when running `bandwidthTest`. Is this expected? Also, I am running this on the Tesla series card (K20 and K40). And the access pattern is s.t. consecutive threads read and write consecutive locations in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Beside useful comments on the question, I'm quoting related parts of section *5.2.13: ECC (Error Correcting Codes)* from the book [the CUDA Handbook](http://www.cudahandbook.com/) by *Nicholas Wilt*. You might find them helpful.

> In exchange for a smaller amount of memory (since some memory is used to record some redundancy) and lower bandwidth, GPUs with ECC enabled can silently correct single-bit errors and report double-bit errors.
>   ECC has the following characteristics:
>    - It reduces the amount of available memory by 12.5%.
>    - It makes context synchronization more expensive.
>    - Uncoalesced memory transactions are more expensive when ECC is enabled than otherwise.